# Docker fails to build - Create React App + Tailwind /bin/sh: craco: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, tailwind-css, craco

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now. I am trying to dockerize a django REST API + react (create-react-app) application. The react application uses craco for building since I am using tailwindcss. I followed the this guide to integrate Tailwind with the React app and it's working when I run yarn start locally.

Guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

The problem is it is throwing **/bin/sh: craco: not found** error when I run it using docker-compose. I even tried adding **RUN yarn add @craco/craco -g** after **RUN yarn** in the frontend Dockerfile but it is showing the same error.

Error when running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
...
Step 8/9 : COPY . /app/frontend/
 ---> 19e0247cde64
Step 9/9 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 43f7d970d460
Removing intermediate container 43f7d970d460
 ---> a20ae2148d4b

Successfully built a20ae2148d4b
Successfully tagged react_frontend:latest
Creating react_frontend_container ... done
Attaching to react_frontend_container
yarn run v1.22.15
$ craco start
frontend_1  | /bin/sh: craco: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
react_frontend_container exited with code 127
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .

RUN yarn

COPY . /app/frontend/
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  ... (postgres db and django api services)

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
      - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
    container_name: react_frontend_container
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `yarn craco start` instead? This should force yarn to look for craco in the dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you map your host directory and volume onto the directories in the image that contain the node modules and the app files.

Try removing this section in the docker-compose file. That way you won't overwrite what's in the image and craco will be available.

```
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/app/frontend
  - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
```

One thing to be aware of when you use docker-compose to both build and run your image, is that the volumes are only mapped during the run phase and not during the build.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks! But once I remove the volumes section, now when I make edits in my code, the changes aren't reflecting. This was initially what the volumes solves, right? So how do I resolve this new issue?

Comment: The simple way is to build the image every time you make changes. Making an image that can work both as a development environment that reacts to changes and also is an image you can deploy is hard. Yours, right now, is an image you can deploy when you're done and is not suited for a fast development feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

[@Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) answer solves the problem but when you edit, your code changes don't reflect.

With the anonymous volume ('/app/frontend/node_modules'), the node_modules directory wouldn't be overwritten by the mounting of the host directory at runtime

By changing your volumes section, you solve your issue and keep the fast development feedback loop

```
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/app/frontend
  - /app/frontend/node_modules
```

You can read more [here](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/)

I had the same issue and solved by doing above ^